# SVN connection error in android app OASVN

Tags: android, authentication, svn

I have given

```
name:<as my wish>
repo URL:<my repo url>
username:<my username>
password :<my password>
private-key:left blank
local folder:/storage/emulated/O/OASVNlite/
```

when i tried to check out it says

> svn:Authentication required for `https://........:443>`Subversion
>   repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't work with my username and password which was working in my PC. tried with different username and password and it worked.